# Slim normalized Restfull route

Tags: routes, slim

My Slim RESTful route works well:

```
$app->get('/course/addresse/:course_id(/)', 'getCourseAddresses');
```

But in this version it does not work:

```
$app->get('/course/:course_id/addresse(/)', 'getCourseAddresses');
```

Why this difference?

I think this one is most typical of a RESTful route:

```
/course/:course_id/addresse
```

I don't understand why the second version does not work.

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: Both routes work! What's the question?

Comment: In Slim API, just first work, second does not.

Comment: I have tested both, they both work!

Comment: What version of Slim are you using?

Answer (score 0):

With new Slim 3 parentesis () don't work, you need to change by [].

But if you need to deal with trailing slash, read official docs:

http://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/route-patterns.html